# JSON.stringify(new Map()) prints '[]' instead of '{}' for a particular org

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary

Do we have a way access to native code of JSON.stringify which we can use or customize? seems in a particular site I am facing this issue where JSON.stringify(new Map()) gives '[]' instead of '{}'. There might be some customizations for this native code is present but I am not able to narrow it down.

Has anyone ever faced this issue? Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(new Map())` returns `{}` for me. Perhaps you have `Map` polyfilled somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem. I get `{}` when I stringify a new Map.

That said, the general approach to solving this type of problem follows:

---

The native code is browser-specific, usually written in C, and may-or-may-not be open source depending on the browser. Either way, it probably isn't very useful to you.

If you want custom handling of a type of object, pass a replacer function as the second argument to [`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and have it do something custom with `Map` objects.

```js
const data = new Map();
const replacer = (key, value) => {
  if (value instanceof Map) {
    return {};
  }
  return value;
};
const json = JSON.stringify(data, replacer, 2);
console.log(json);
```

Comment: The implementation of `Map` giving `{}` isn't implementation-dependent - `JSON.stringify` will [iterate over enumerable own-properties](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-serializejsonobject) and put them inside `{}`s, but Maps have no enumerable own properties. Since OP has `JSON.stringify(new Map())` giving `'[]'`, then `Map.prototype.toJSON` has probably been overwritten.

Answer (score -1):

You can change `Map.prototype.toJSON` to return `[]` instead of `{}`:

```js
Map.prototype.toJSON = () => [];
console.log(JSON.stringify(new Map()));
```

So if you're looking for why a serialized Map gives `[]` instead of `{}`, search the codebase for changes to `toJSON`.

(but this is weird and will break most developer's usual expectations - Maps aren't serializable, so attempting to do implicitly so should be avoided)